# populating listview with names of sharedpreferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

i want to develop an activity for my application where i want to populate my listview with the names of the shared preferences stored by the application previously.

At the same time i also want to add "add and delete" functionality on my listview where if i click on delete the shared preference associated with that row should also be deleted and the row entry also.

Comment: And what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: how do i retrive names of sharedpreferences nad populate my listview with those names

Comment: By the way, have you tried to find the solution yourself by googling, trying some tutorials, etc.?

Comment: i havent tried it myself, but i have searched it over google. but i couldnt find it . i just need a simple example. i will develop it further.

Comment: So you should really consider trying some solutions and seeing what goes well and what goes wrong. Or you should hire a freelancer for money if you want someone to provide you with the working solution.

Comment: i dont need a full solution , give me an example or just simply guide me how this can be achieved.

Comment: i think you are a teacher, if you could just provide me an helping hand , i will show you what i have developed from what you have told (within 6 hours) and one more thing, i am new to android/ programming, but still i have to submit a project on android in my college. i dont have money to hire a freelancer. you help will be respected